# Why doesn't waitid block until child terminates?

Tags: linux, clone

```
void *stack;
stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
if (-1 == clone(child_thread, stack + STACK_SIZE, 0, NULL)) {                                                                                                                                                                           
    perror("clone failed:");
}   
while(waitid(P_ALL, 0, NULL, WEXITED) != 0){ 
    perror("waitid failed:");
    sleep(1);
}
```

The manual says:

> If  a  child  has  already changed state, then these calls return
>   immediately.  Otherwise they block until either a child changes state

But in fact it returns immediately :

```
waitid failed:: No child processes
waitid failed:: No child processes
...
```

Any advice?

Comment: What does the `child_thread()` function do?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson,it `sleep(20)` then exits.

Answer (score 1):

You are using PID options. Look further in the man page:

The following Linux-specific options are for use with children  created
       using clone(2); they cannot be used with waitid():

```
   __WCLONE
          Wait  for "clone" children only.  If omitted then wait for "non-
          clone" children only.  (A "clone" child is one which delivers no
          signal, or a signal other than SIGCHLD to its parent upon termi-
          nation.)  This option is ignored if __WALL is also specified.

   __WALL (Since Linux 2.4) Wait for  all  children,  regardless  of  type
          ("clone" or "non-clone").

   __WNOTHREAD
          (Since  Linux  2.4) Do not wait for children of other threads in
          the same thread group. This was the default before Linux 2.4.
```

Comment: Are you still using waitid, or did you notice that these options do not work with waitid? You need to use waitpid.

Comment: I replaced with `waitid` with `waitpid`, but still no luck:(

Comment: So, you are doing waitpid(-1, NULL, __WALL)?

Comment: yes, I did `waitpid(P_ALL, NULL, __WALL);`, does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the specifics of what you are trying to get done here, but by using waitid in the following way might help:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

...

siginfo_t signalInfo;
waitid(P_ALL, 0, &signalInfo, WEXITED | WSTOPPED | WNOWAIT | WNOHANG);
```

Then check for the following in signalInfo to know what happened whenever child exits:

```
signalInfo.si_signo : For Signal Number
signalInfo.si_code : Usually SIGCHLD
signalInfo.si_errno) : Any error code set
signalInfo.si_status : For exit code of the child code
```

Note: Using WNOWAIT makes the OS preserve the child process resource usage even after it is killed. You may/may not use this option. If you do, you will have to explicitly call waitid on the child again without the WNOWAIT option.

Reference: See man pages for waitid for more information on this.