# Waiting for cloned child in assembly with waitid syscall

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I am trying to wait for a process I have cloned. However, when the parent makes the syscall to `waitid` I get an `-1 ECHILD` when using strace. This despite the clone call returning a PID for the created child as seen here:

```
clone(child_stack=0x7ffe2b412d10, flags=CLONE_NEWNS|CLONE_NEWUTS|CLONE_NEWIPC|CLONE_NEWPID) = 3735
waitid(P_PID, 3735, NULL, WEXITED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
```

If I make a loop that repeatedly calls `waitid` it eventually gives the expected result of waiting for the child. That leads me to believe that there's some race condition where the child hasn't started properly yet, but has been given a PID.

Below is the relevant assembly code:

```
_start: 
    mov rax, SYS_CLONE
    mov rdi, CLONE_FLAGS
    mov rsi, rsp
    mov rdx, 0
    mov r10, 0
    syscall

    cmp rax, 0
    je _clone   

    mov rdi, PPID       
    mov rsi, rax    ; pid
    mov rdx, 0
    mov r10, 4      ; exited
    mov rax, SYS_WAITID
    syscall

    mov rdi, OK_EXIT
    jmp _exit

_clone:
    mov rax, SYS_EXECVE
    mov rdi, [rsp + 16]
    lea rsi, [rsp + 16]
    lea rdx, [rsp + 40]
    syscall

    mov rdi, rax
    jmp _exit   

_exit:
    mov rax, SYS_EXIT
    syscall
```

Note that I'm passing NULL as the third (`siginfo_t *infop`) argument to `waitid` and I suspect that I need to setup that struct properly to make everything work, but I haven't found any examples on how to do that in assembly. How can I do that? Or am I mistaken and I just have to resort to the looping workaround I mentioned?

Comment: `infop` is optional, it's unrelated to your problem. Setting it up would be as simple as allocating the appropriate amount of space somewhere, conveniently from the stack.

Comment: @Jester Any idea what the problem could be (with respect to the timing issue of calling waitid on a cloned pid and getting ECHILD as return value)? Also I've tried to find documentation for `siginfo_t`, but onlt found some hard to read source files. Is there any docs you know of?

Comment: I only found [this question here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853524/why-doesnt-waitid-block-until-child-terminates) but not very helpful except to show that others have run into similar issue. I have checked the kernel source, `ECHILD` is returned sooner than anything is done to the siginfo.

Comment: Your `clone` call doesn't include `SIGCHLD` in the flags
, so you're creating a so-called *clone child*. If you pass `WEXITED|__WALL` as the flags to `waitid`, does your wait work better? Without `__WALL` (or `__WCLONE`), waitid should wait for non-clone children only.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I just included `SIGCHLD` in the flags and the `waitid` now always succeed. Weird that the waitid eventually works (e.g. when I repeatedly call waitid untill it doesn't error out), any idea why? Put your comment in an answer if you want some internet points :)

Comment: When you had to loop for awhile in order for the waitid to succeed, when did it finally succeed? Was it after the execve'd process exited?

Comment: No, it was before the child/execve exited. It worked like it should, it just took a little while before the parent waited successfully. I suspect there was some race condition (since the problem was intermittent).

Comment: I did some testing (in C), without `SIGCHLD` in the `clone` flags and with only `WEXITED` in the `waitid` flags. `waitid` was placed in a loop. `waitid` returned an `ECHILD` error repeatedly, *until the clone child did an execl*, and then it waited normally. (I had the child sleep for 5 seconds before doing the exec, and it execed a `sleep 10`). Could that be approximately the same behavior you saw?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That seems to be it! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this case, one needs to add `flags=SIGCHLD | ...` when calling `clone`, so that `SIGCHLD` is sent by the child at exit as described in [include/uapi/linux/sched.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/sched.h?v=3.16#L7).

This GAS code only works with `SIGCHLD`

```
.globl _start

.text
a:.quad 1
  .quad 0
b:.quad d

c:
 mov $56,%rax
#SIGCHLD
 mov $17,%rdi
 mov $b,%rsi
 syscall
 ret

d:
 mov $35,%rax
 mov $a,%rdi
 syscall
 mov $60,%rax
 syscall

_start:
 call c
 mov %rax,%rsi
 mov $247,%rax
 mov $1,%rdi
 mov $4,%r10
 syscall
 mov $60,%rax
 syscall
```